# How to get the value of an HTML element

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of a `<p/>` element using JavaScript, but instead, I get `undefined`:

HTML:

```
<p id="bool_"> _test_</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("bool_").value;
alert(x); // Alerts 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
var x =document.getElementById("bool_").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `innerText` property of a HTML element.

```
const x = document.getElementById("bool_").innerText;
alert(x);
```